# Overloading on l-values an

Tags: c++, overloading

How can one invoke the second (overloaded) function?
(This example is present in Savitch's C++ textbook.)

(1)  `int& f(); // will be used in any l-value invocation`

(2)  `const int& f() const; // will be used in any r-value invocation`

I thought the first one is invoked in (a) and the second one in (b). But it is not.

(a)   `f() = 123;    // the first one is invoked.`

(b)   `f() + 3;      // the first one is also invoked.`

Answer (score 2):

Only member functions can be const. So let's assume f actually is a member function in the textbook.

When the compiler has a choice between a const and a non const member function it will only use the const one if it has to. This is when the object the function is called on is const.

```
class A {
public:
    int &f();
    const int& f() const;
};


void func()
{
    A a;
    a.f(); // calls non const version
    const A ca;
    ca.f(); // call const version
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> (1) int& f(); // will be used in any l-value invocation
>
> (2) const int& f() const; // will be used in any r-value invocation

These comments are wrong. If they appear in a textbook then I would recommend getting a different textbook.

Version `2` will be used when the expression denoting the object has `const` type, otherwise version `1` is used. It is nothing at all to do with lvalues and rvalues. Using Eelke's class definition:

```
 A().f();    // invokes (1) on an rvalue

 A const a;
 a.f();     // invokes (2) on an lvalue
```

In your examples you don't actually show whether you are working on a `const` instance or not, but judging by your results, both must have been on a non-const one.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading works on function parameters not by return type.

```
double f();
int f();
```

These are not overloading.

But these are:

```
double f();
int f(int);
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking about the difference between `const` and non `const` return type. Which one would be called in which situations.